# Arduino EEPROM crashes when writing a large block

Tags: c++, arduino, eeprom

I'm trying to write a uint32_t array to EEPROM with EEPROM_writeAnything, but when I call it, it seems to just crash out of where it's running. Hard to tell since the Serial debug I'm outputting never gets output.

Code is like this:

```
        uint32_t dataBuf[SYNC_MAX_COLS];
        memcpy(dataBuf, buf, SYNC_MAX_COLS*sizeof(uint32_t));
        for(int i=DATA_EEPROM_START; i<DATA_EEPROM_START+(SYNC_MAX_COLS*sizeof(uint32_t)); i+=sizeof(uint32_t))
        {
            EEPROM_writeAnything(i, dataBuf[i-DATA_EEPROM_START]);
        }
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe running out of memory?

Comment: Blowing the stack is a distinct possibility.  Why are you using dataBuf at all?  Just use buf.